# Python - how to convert a LP_c_char_p to str or bytes?

Tags: python, c++, json, callback, ctypes

this is my first question in stackoverflow. 
I've been looking for the answer to this but I didn't find it.

I am trying to get a callback which should contain a string. This callback comes from a C++ dll. Everything related to dll loading and callback work, but when it comes to parse the callback content it crashes.

Debugging I've seen how my callback implementation is called and I can print a "Hello" there, but the returned object by the callback cannot be serialized. This is the error:

```
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'LP_c_char_p'
```

This is how I load the dll. I am using cdll:

```
self.dxc_dll = cdll.DxC
```

My callback declaration (using ctypes) is this:

```
self.callback_type = CFUNCTYPE(c_char_p, POINTER(c_char_p))
self.callback = self.callback_type(self.callback_impl)
```

The method, callback_impl has this signature:

```
def callback_impl(self, result):
    print("Callback works. Result: ", result)
    my_object = MyClass(result)
    ...
```

And this is MyClass init constructor:

```
def __init__(self, json_string):
    self.__dict__ = json.loads(json_string)
```

In my C++ library, the Callback signature is declared this way (it works using PInvoke and C#, I've already done that, but not in this case):

```
CCallback::CCallback(char *(__stdcall  *func)(char *))
```

So I don't know if it could be related with the json.loads behaviour or it's necessary to convert the **LP_c_char_p** to str or bytes before.

- I am using the standard ctypes and json libraries included with
  Python.
- I am using PyCharm 2017 on Windows 10 x64, Python 3.6.1
  32bit and the dll library is 32 bit version compiled with Visual
  Studio 2013 (also under Windows)

Is there anything I can do? 
Thanks in advance for your help. If you know more information in order to help, I'll be glad to include it.
Regards.

Comment: Your prototype should be `WINFUNCTYPE(c_char_p, c_char_p)`. What are you returning for the `char *` result from the callback? ctypes will leak memory here if you don't manage this properly.

Comment: I am returning a json string and I am trying to deserialize it. I already had that "memory leak" message once. I will try you solution on Monday. Anyways, if I use WINFUNCTYPE, should I use: self.dxc_dll = windll.DxC ? Thank you!

Comment: The callback is declared as `__stdcall`, which in 32-bit Windows has the callee (i.e. the ctypes callback closure that calls your Python function) clean up the stack with the `ret` instruction. It's important to set the calling convention correctly to prevent stack corruption. `WINFUNCTYPE` is stdcall, and `CFUNCTYPE` is cdecl. Also, if you're calling functions in the DLL that are declared as `__stdcall`, then you should use `WinDLL('DxC')`. On the other hand, in 64-bit Windows, there's no difference between cdecl and stdcall.

Comment: Regarding the leak, if you create a `c_char_p` for the return string and store a reference to it in a global keep-alive dict, then you can return a `c_void_p` instead. To do this, change the callback prototype and cast the `c_char_p` pointer to a `c_void_p`. ctypes won't create a leak for returning a `void *` pointer. It's up to you to manage the objects in the global keep-alive dict, to remove them when you know the C library no longer needs them.

Comment: I tried your solution and now I'm getting this error:
"Got exception  Procedure probably called with too many arguments (12 bytes in excess)"
The exception is obvious, but comparing the function signature in both, C++ and Python (when I call it), it's the same. And it worked with cdll (CFUNCTYPE).
Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: The callback is stdcall (`WINFUNCTYPE`), but not necessarily the DLL's exported functions. Check the prototypes in the header. That error is probably from calling a cdecl function (`CFUNCTYPE`, caller cleanup) as stdcall (callee cleanup). After the call, ctypes sees that the stack pointer is less than the original stack pointer and assumes arguments were pushed on the stack that weren't cleaned, which its expects a stdcall function to do.

Comment: Finally I found the problem. Now I have to struggle with other stuff but thanks to eryksun. It was related to WINFUCTYPE, __stdcall but also because de dll was x86. It must be x64, then I got another problem because I was using Python 32. I changed to Python x64, PyCharm 64bits and a x64 dll (even though is a Win32 app I used the x64 release version). In addition, WINFUNCTYPE to declare the function and windll to load de library. With this configuration I succeed to load it and use it correctly. Thanks!

Comment: Again, check the prototypes to load the library using `CDLL` if most of the functions are cdecl (the default if nothing is specified) or `WinDLL` if most functions use stdcall, and override this individually if a function uses a different calling convention. That things are working in x64 means nothing because the x64 ABI ignores stdcall and cdecl declarations. 64-bit Windows uses a new calling convention that passes integer/pointer arguments in registers rcx, rdx, r8, and r9 and otherwise uses the stack with callee cleanup.

Comment: Everything is fine now eryksun :) thank you. I don't know how to give you points or something like that